# Cannot use IOptions in console app .NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, config, configuration-files

I have a console application where I am building up the configuration

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
   .Build();

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<ResourceConfiguration>(config.GetSection("ResourceConfiguration"));
```

This doesnt work

```
  Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action<ResourceConfiguration>' (29, 55)
```

I have the following in my using (as well as my own namespaces)

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.IO;

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
   .Build();
```

Returns IConfigurationRoot which may be the issue?

What am I doing wrong?

This is .NET Core 3.1

Paul

Comment: What `using` statements do you have at the top of your file? Which nuget packages do you have in your project?

Comment: The error says that  `Configure<ResourceConfiguration>` expects a *method*, not a section. Perhaps you're trying to use the wrong extension metthod?

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos said, you need to "cast", try this: `config.GetSection("ResourceConfiguration").Get<ResourceConfiguration>()`

Comment: @Valter that's not what I said. You can't cast an `IConfigurationSection` to an `Action`. The question's code is fine, exactly the same as [the documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-di-services-to-configure-options) and code I've used

Comment: I miss read the error...

Comment: How would I do this using a method?

Comment: Is this the *actual code*? Or is it `ervices.AddOptions().Configure< ResourceConfiguration>()`? `services.Configure<ResourceConfiguration>(` wouldn't throw such an exception. `AddOptions` returns an OptionsBuilder though, whose [Configure method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-di-services-to-configure-options) expects an action

Comment: Have you included Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions?

Comment: I needed ConfigurationExtensions thanks!  If that can be added as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have created a console app using .NET 6 to help you out.

Check the code below and let us know if it worked. =)

**AppSettings.json**

```
{
    "SETUP_OPTIONS": 
    {
        "MyProperty": 100,
        "MyProperty2": "Success!"
    }
}
```

**usings required**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

**SetupOptions class**

```
public class SetupOptions
{
    public const string ConfigKey = "SETUP_OPTIONS";

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();

    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection, configuration);

    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    await serviceProvider.GetService<MyAppClass>().RunAsync(args);
}

private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    // AppSettings IOptions configuration
    serviceCollection.AddOptions<SetupOptions>().Bind(configuration.GetSection(SetupOptions.ConfigKey));

    serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyAppClass>();
}
```

**MyAppClass.cs**

```
public class MyAppClass
{
    private readonly SetupOptions _setupOptions;

    // Inject IOptions in your constructor
    public MyAppClass(IOptions<SetupOptions> setupOptions)
    {
        _setupOptions = setupOptions?.Value;
    }

    public async Task RunAsync(string[] args)
    {
        // Use your Setup Options value loaded from appsettings file.
        var myPropertyValue = _setupOptions.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, SetBasePath argument is not correct. We could use something like Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) or a simple Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: Without all of the service stuff, the code looks like: myOpts = config.GetSection(SetupOptions.ConfigKey).Get<SetupOptions>()

Answer (score 6):

You probably missing the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`.